# Python install error "A newer version of the Python launcher is already installed"

Tags: python

I am trying to reinstall Python, so I go `control panel > uninstall > Python 3.6.2`. It succeeds, but when I try to download `3.6.*`, it says that I can't download because there is already a version of Python3 installed.

I tried to clean the registry, deleted all files named "Python", but still see the error. I even deleted the path Python in `PATH`.

[image: Image of error]

Comment: remember to use ccleaner or similars to delete registry keys, and remember to restart the computer too

Comment: It doesn't say a version of Python is installed. It says a version of [the Python **launcher**](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) is installed.

Answer (score 8):

This may be a silly solution, but for me the issue was the `Python Launcher` still listed in the apps list after the uninstall. Uninstalled it separately, afterwards reinstalled Python without the error.

[image: Python launcher in Apps]

Comment: This is the correct answer in OP's case. After all, the screencap quite clearly says that the problem is the Python launcher.

Answer (score 3):

The installer/uninstaller does not do a good job of cleaning up after itself (and that's being generous).  What worked for me:

1. Remove all python binary folders from `Program Files` and `Users\<username>\AppData`
2. Clean the PATH of any and all mentions of python
3. Search the registry in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Features` for any values with python, then delete the *containing key*.  The key names are things like "03CEBFB8CC334B3148F9B330F67264A6" (that's an example, not an actual one, since the actuals I deleted)

#3 is the one that actually got it past the hurdle, but #1 and #2 should be done anyway.

Comment: Even this didn't work lmao. I removed the whole containing keys, not just the specific values. This is some cringe. World would be a better place without Python.

Comment: @KulaGGin Do you still need help with this? I finally figured it out after an atrocious waste of time doing so.

Comment: @Coldblackice yep. I managed to fix this and wrote an answer on how I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70464698/6693304 . All the other answers, unfortunately, didn't work for me.

Comment: @KulaGGin Thanks, but mine wasn't solved with that answer, either. I had to dig even deeper, which was very annoying. Anyway, I guess I'll type up how I finally fixed mine in case anybody else gets stuck after trying the below answers.

Comment: @Coldblackice Very good, this might be the ultimate solution. When I was trying to solve mine, I wanted to find the registry keys that Python installer uses to determine if other versions are installed, but I didn't understand how to find them.

Comment: @KulaGGin Thanks. As a general tip, aside from log files, the go-to way to find out what registry keys a program is using is via "Process Monitor", then filtering for whichever process name you're wanting to track. Afterward, click on the "Tools" menu then "Registry Summary". It'll show all registry keys that were accessed/read/modified. Alternatively, there's also "RegistryChangesView", which will show the most recent changes to the registry... however that's helpful only when the registry is being changed, not merely read. Process Monitor is best, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

My issue persisted despite all the above. If you're still having issues:

I realized the Python installer shows a log file link... wish I had noticed it sooner. Click to open that log, search for "***Detected***". Find all lines with "***Detected related package***". These lines are specifically what's tripping the installer. Notice the version numbers are higher than the version you're installing, along with the "***Operation: Downgrade***"s).

[image: Python Installer Log - Detected packages]

Once you find these GUIDs in your log, you'll need to search each of them in the registry. I use a free registry tool called ***Resplendence Registry Registrar Manager*** (I have no connection with them), which searches the registry blazingly fast and will show everywhere it finds something. But you can also just use Windows' native RegEdit, as well.

[image: GUIDs found in registry]

When you find one of these GUIDs in the registry, rename the key by adding an underscore to it, like below. This is the equivalent of "deleting" them -- as far as the Python installer can tell -- but without actually deleting them. You can easily revert them if needed.

Re-run the Python installer and it should now install just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix all this Python cringe by doing this:

Download newest version of Python for your version after the first point. In this case it's Python 3.6, so I downloaded the latest available - 3.6.8:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/

Run it.

Check the checkbox "Add Python to Path":
[image]

Press on the Custom Installation button:
[image]

Press Next:

[image]

Install:

[image]

It should install. Now go to `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features`, press RMB and uninstall:
[image]

Now run your wanted Python 3.6.X installation again.

If it still gives you the "A newer version of the Python launcher is already installed", run the latest installer again as in all the previous steps, but instead, check the "Install for All Users" checkbox:

[image]

Then uninstall this latest version again.
And then install your wanted Python 3.6.X installation again.

I'm throwing hands in the air, personally

[image]

I had to do it just now for 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10 versions because I had problems with uninstalling and installing with errors "no python installation was detected" and "A newer version of the Python launcher is already installed". Why do I have all these different versions of Python? Because different programs want different versions of Python installed and refuse to work with any other(lmao).

World would be a better place without Python.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the system console.
2. Show the installation with:

   winget install Python.Python.3.10 -i --scope machine -s winget --force

`--force` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the files of the old version python and try to re-install to uninstall the older version you can do it from control panel

Comment: I cleaned the registry, deleted all files named "python", still such an error. Even deleted the path to the python in PATH. List of programms has not Python.

Answer (score 0):

Install another version. For example, if you are installing a 64-bit installation, then try to install 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Download zip file from below URL.
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/python-3.6.0-embed-amd64.zip
Copy all the contents to the python folder which is registered in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For me, the solution to the problem (a newer version of the python launcher is already installed) was to install it via the web installer from the website (https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Download the Windows x86-64 web installer. The installer took for his series (3.7). Oddly enough, it worked the first time. Previously, the registry was cleaned, and the removal of possible traces of the program - all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I also deleted files in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies, this might help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Within the installer of the lower python version (where it complained), on the main page, select customize.

Then on the next page, **de-select py launcher** and select install for all users.

Hint: The newer launcher also works for the older version - so no need to try to over-install the older py launcher over the newer.